# Exporting certificate from keychain, password not accepted

Tags: ios, keychain

I am trying to export my iOS certificate as a Personal Information Exchange (PKCS12) to be used with push notification. When exporting I am prompted with a password dialog:

```
Keychain Access wants to export key "MyKey" from your keychain.
To allow this, enter the "login" keychain password.
```

However the password is never accepted. Even tried to Reset my keychain by taking the following steps:

```
1. Going to Keychain Access => Preferences => Reset My Default Keychain 
2. Prompted with a password dialog: Please enter your login password. 
   This password will be used to create your new keychain.
```

Even so the password is not accepted when exporting the certificate.
My Mac Mini is running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.2.

Any idea if I am missing a step or how to set the keychain password?

Comment: 1.Check your certificate available.2.Don't enter special characters.(check your IM also)

Comment: Hi @Lumialxk could you explain in more detail. 1. What do you mean with  checking available certificate? 2. I was using a special character in my password but I just tried a password without a special character and still have the same issue. What should I check regarding the IM are you referring to Instant Messaging? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. I was on a Mac using TeamViewer, when I disconnected from TeamViewer and used the machine directly the issue was non-existent.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the keychain password dialog is not functioning when used remotely. Only the 'Deny' button was working. When I did the same thing locally on the Mac it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

Wow - I had the same issue, but I was on the mac locally. However I'm using a utility called ShareMouse that allows you to use the same keyboard/mouse on multiple machines. So I tried turning off ShareMouse and going through the process with the keyboard/mouse connected to the Mac and it worked! :p

Comment: I was using an input sharing program called Synergy (with the Mac as the client).  Temporarily turning of Synergy as I exported the key did the trick.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.